# Need to replace a new line in xpage

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

I want to replace newline in text by space or comma in serverside javascript(XPage). I tried the following code.

```
function setValueFunction(lines){
var oneline = "";
while(lines.length > 0) {
if(@Contains(lines, @NewLine())) {
oneline = oneline+@Left(lines, @NewLine())+";";
lines = @Right(lines, @NewLine());
} 
else{
oneline=oneline+lines
lines=""
}
}
print("Final line="+oneline)
}
```

**Input** every word has only one new line .example First\nLine\nSecond\nLine\nThird\nLine

First

Line

Second

Line

Third

Line

But it is printing in the new line only.

**OutPut**

31-01-2014 AM 10:48:25  HTTP JVM: Final line=First

31-01-2014 AM 10:48:25  HTTP JVM: ;Line

31-01-2014 AM 10:48:25  HTTP JVM: ;Second

31-01-2014 AM 10:48:25  HTTP JVM: ;Line

31-01-2014 AM 10:48:25  HTTP JVM: ;Third

31-01-2014 AM 10:48:25  HTTP JVM: ;Line

**I need output as below**

First;Line;Second;Line;Third;Line

I tried replace all,@replaceSubstring,@replace all. but I could not get the solution.
Please help me get out of this problem.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should cover and replace all kind of newlines:

```
@ReplaceSubstring(lines, [@NewLine(), '\r'], ";")
```

Comment: `var temp=@Left(CommentsVal, @NewLine()); 
oneline = oneline+@Left(temp,@Length(temp)-1)+";" 
CommentsVal = @Right(CommentsVal, @NewLine());
`
I made few change, this is one is working fine. but It is not straight way.

Knut Herrmann : Great.It works perfectly fine. your code is pretty much simple and good. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the JavaScript replace to remove \n (new line) and \r (carraige return) wich are creating the new line.

```
text.replace(/[\n\r]/g, '');
```

Comment: Thanks Saiz. I need solution in server side. Herrmann solution works perfecly fine.